# Requiero aclaración de mi Ban

Tags: soporte, moderación, chat, suspensiones-chat

Hoy me banearon del Chat, el motivo no me queda claro ni se me permitió defenderme o aclarar mis dichos que pudieron haberlo provocado.

Como no tengo ni idea de cual es el curso a seguir, ni como contactarme con la persona que me baneo para que lo habláramos en privado. Pido que me lo aclare por este medio.

Lamento molestar al resto con esta publicación, se que no es de su interés.

Comment: Hola, probablemente publicaste algún mensaje que contiene malas palabras o escribiste algún adjetivo que indica alguna cualidad negativa de algún usuario, ¿no recuerdas algo?

Comment: DIjo que la moderacion se esta conbirtiendo o es una dictadura, tomando en concideracion como actuo gbianchi con el tema ....

Comment: aqui esta lo aclarado por el diamantado gbianchi: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65103952#65103952

Comment: ahora, no concidero que sea una falta de respeto... creo que simplemente yussef se cerro y estaba llavando el dialogo por mal camino... pero esto no se si sea sancionable como se hizo... creo que hay canales y mejor formas de hacer las cosas ... yo conociendo como estan ahora mismo los humores preferi apegarme a lo que se indico y cree el post... ya que no esto tampoco de acuerdo con lo que se hizo en ambas partes...

Comment: Es importante recordar que no se debe faltar al respeto entre los usuarios del sitio y en este caso. Es la historia de siempre, usuarios nuevos que quieren cambiar las reglas del sitio a su conveniencia, en este caso como ha mencionado Gonzalo hay exponer esas "nuevas ideas" en META.

Comment: no creo que sea una nueva idea... simplemente creo que es algo que se ha venido haciendo, pero que habia pasado desapersivido por la moderacion y/o en el camino se les olvido lo que se habia llegado a concenso en el 2017 y 2020... por eso hice la otra publicacion y respuesta en meta ... a ver si ya aterrizamos con el tema ...

Comment: @Jorgesys Es al revés las normas del sitio me animan a realizar ediciones profundas y no solo estéticas a las publicaciones. A los que no les guste eso, son libres (ellos) de exponer sus nuevas idea en META. Pero eso es otro tema. Respondiendo a tu pregunta, claro que recuerdo lo que dije, la aclaración que pido es como eso sería una falta de respeto. Yo al contrario, considero que la falta de respeto es hacia mi persona, tanto con la actitud que se ha tomado hacia mi y por el mismo ban

Answer (score 9):

La respuesta de Francisco es exactamente lo que explicaría yo, con una sola excepción:

- No puedes decir que es una dictadura; si bien puede estar actuando de esa forma no es correcto....

No, no solo nadie actúa de esa forma, si no que lanzar acusaciones porque si, y elevar el tono de la conversación, no es correcto ni amigable.

Ya se les dijo varios veces a varios usuarios en el chat, que no expresen sus quejas contra alguien en particular, y que si tienen dudas las consulten en meta, donde la visibilidad de las mismas es a toda la comunidad, y no a los 10 usuarios que con suerte ven el chat.

Yo segui las reglas. Puedo estar equivocado? si, soy humano y me puedo confundir. He borrado comentarios que no debia. He mandado publicaciones a la basura que no correspondia. Asi como los otros usuarios usan mal los reportes, aceptan ediciones erroneas, o se quejan de publicaciones que estan correctas. Todos cometemos errores. Yo sigo pensando que lo mio estuvo bien, porque absolutamente nunca quedo claro el criterio, y aplique el mio.

Y por eso, los mande a consultar en meta, no a enfrentarme a mi.

Tu baneo fue para que te calmaras, antes que dijeras algo peor. Y ya les fui avisando que bajaran los tonos y llevaran las cosas por donde corresponde.

Comment: "que no expresen sus quejas contra alguien en particular..." El formato de meta no permite debates largos, de hecho, se promueve que el exceso de comentarios pasen al chat. "Tu baneo fue para que te calmaras, antes que dijeras algo peor." Aunque responde la pregunta, no estoy de acuerdo con el motivo. Al menos yo odio que asuman cosas de mi sin más y me traten de calmar como animal salvaje. Yo creo que, como es normal en un ser humano, te equivocaste, el ban debía ser cuando dijera algo peor y no para "calmar".

Comment: @Dante, en los últimos meses van contra Gonza y los moderadores, me parece muy injusto, ellos no son empleados de SO, tampoco CM, y así lo fueran, existen formas adecuadas para formular una problemática y propuestas de mejora como adultos. Por otro lado, dudo muchísimo que haya dicho “que se calme” en plan “animal salvaje”. Se le avisó, hizo caso omiso, considera que es reincidente, pequeño dato que cambia el accionar de cualquiera, ¿verdad?

Comment: Primero quiero agradecerte que hayas tenido la deferencia y el tiempo para responderme. Tengo claro cuales fueron las palabras que detonaron el ban, me hubiera gustado que me explicaras como esas palabras te resultaron una falta de respeto, porque ni esa fue mi intención y tampoco me parece que lo sean. Pero es que ahora (por lo que entiendo) es que ni quiera ese fue el motivo, si no que era para que me calmara....bueno eso no era necesario, soy una persona bastante calmada.

Comment: Mis dichos si podrían catalogarse como una critica, la cual creo que ni te interesa que la clarifique, así que no te haré perder tiempo con eso. Lo que si deseo clarificar es que entre nosotros hemos tenido varios desacuerdos, y yo siempre y en cada momento te he tratado con respeto, y sin embargo yo si me he sentido irrespetado por ti en más de alguna oportunidad

Comment: @fredyfx Te pido que no distorsiones la realidad. Yo discutía con otro usuario y fue gbianchi quien libremente se integró a la discusión, con lo cual el solo se expuso al debate, a mi nadie me dijo "que se calme" ni era necesario hacerlo ni fue ese el motivo del ban. A mi no se me advirtió que la discusión lo estaba incomodando, ni yo tenia modo de saberlo, porque repito fue él quien se integró sin haberlo invocado.

Comment: ¿Reincidente? Te pido por favor que cuides tus palabras. Yo he participado en un sin número de comunidades desde el año 96' y es primera vez en mi vida que banean.

Comment: @fredyfx entiendo, y tenés razón. Sin embargo, trato de decir que el ban fue muy temprano, pues el dialogo no fue tan agresivo. Además, en mi caso, que me traten de calmar, sobre todo con aislamiento, me enfurece más.

Comment: @Yussef lamentablemente, la sociedad juzga las acciones más que las intenciones...

Comment: @Yussef vamos por partes: 1. No estoy distorsionando la realidad, estás interpretando desde otro ángulo, no me estoy refiriendo a lo que pasó en la sala de chat, estoy haciendo referencia a lo que dijo Dante; es correcto, a ti nadie te dijo que te calmes, por esto mismo, estás apuntando a un lado "distorsionado" al cual, no me estoy refiriendo.

Comment: 2. Sí, reincidente, no es la primera vez que dices cosas sobre una "dictadura" en la sala de chat, inclusive lo has vuelto a mencionar en una publicación reciente en Meta. Si esta palabra te ha causado malestar, disculpa, quizás haya otra que exprese exactamente el mismo concepto de repetición constante. Y sí, cuido mucho lo que digo y sé que si me equivoco, pido disculpas, este lugar es especial para mi y quiero que también lo sea para todos los que andan compartiendo espacio tiempo conmigo.

Comment: 3. Me parece genial que estés en comunidades desde el 96, todo un logro enorme, gracias por colaborar con todos los desarrolladores desde ese entonces, son poquitos los que logran mantenerse en este mundo colaborativo por un largo tiempo. Mis más sinceras felicitaciones por ello :D

Comment: @DanteS. Ahora ya te entiendo, el asunto fue por efecto de haber sido "muy temprano". Eso tendrá que verlo el buen Gonza.

Comment: @fredyfx Ok estimado, creo que yo he entendido otra cosa totalmente distinta de tus palabras. Mil disculpas

Comment: Normal bro, todo fresh~ Peace n love and hakuna matata :D

Answer (score 5):

Si es de nuestro interés conocer los motivos de los baneos y tratar de que todos, mejoremos para evitarlo, el baneo es el último método que consideraría como herramienta dentro de la moderación, pero hay veces que es justo y necesario.

Lamento decirte que aunque estaba apoyándote en el tema y lo sigo asiendo, ***si estoy de acuerdo con tu baneo del chat... y tambien estoy de acuerdo con que lo preguntes aqui...*** debemos aprender a controlar las emisiones y a no exaltarnos, utilizar la inteligencia emocional es importante en cualquier ámbito profesional y no te dejes llevar por lo que te dicen... esto es difícil de aprender pero importante, a veces necesitamos un tiempo para encontrar el norte adecuado aunque no compartas la misma opinión que otros usuarios.

***Nota:*** a mi también me ha pasado y es estado en peor posición que la tuya. Tengo hater hasta por solo respirar.

Si te hubieran baneado del sitio no hubiera estado de acuerdo, pero pude observar que has podido hacer los comentarios que hiciste, incluso este post.

***Ante todo el respeto a todos los usuarios por igual.***

No le lleves la contraria a la moderación, si te dicen has un hilo aparte, publícalo en meta, usted hágalo. Aunque no estés de acuerdo, no perderás nada.

- Al final **si tienes** la razón quedara evidenciada la mala moderación.
- Al final **si no tienes** la razón, quedara por escrito, en donde debe ser, y la forma correcta en que debe ir la comunidad.

***El Motivo:***

En cuanto al motivo, claramente estabas llevando por mal camino la conversación en el chat, vi cómo te exaltabas al no convencer a gbianchi de tu postura... no es a él a quien tienes que convencer es a la comunidad.

Yo pregunte por que te había baneado y esta fue la respuesta:

> @FranciscoNuñezIALover no lo banee por eso... Lo banee por lo que dijo

Y esta es la línea de chat de [referencia](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65103952#65103952):

> @gbianchi ahí está la pregunta en META, la cual tiene tu opinión
> personal. Y como está es una dictadura, tu opinión personal pesa más
> que la mía

No puedes decir que es una ***dictadura***; si bien puede estar actuando de esa forma no es correcto, sigue siendo de humanos el equivocarse y el así lo admitió en uno de los chat anteriores [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/65103848#65103848):

> Y si me equivoque, me lo hacen saber bien, porque tambien soy humano y
> cometo errores

El con este chat, está abierto a retomar el tema, cuando se llegue a un consenso.

Answer (score 0):

Antes de responder la pregunta quiero empezar con la descripcion del chat

> Stack Overflow en español

> Chat de la comunidad de Stackoverflow en
> español. A veces charlamos sobre temas de programación, discutimos
> preguntas y/o respuestas, hablamos de tecnología y otras cosas. Habla,
> convive, conversa, responde, pregunta, pero siempre desde el respeto.
> es.stackoverflow.com y la razon por la que nos demoro, es que
> queriamos que las reglas del juego en el chat sean claras

---

Una vez aclarado esto, en toda la red de meta esta prohibido expresarse con idealogias politicas ,religiosas y/o de generos(como ejemplo basta con ir al meta principal y buscar preguntas de lo comentado)

Aun asi, a pesar de que seamos de la red exchange, los usuarios de stackoverflow en español(incluyendo los mods) creamos una linea virtual en la que no se puede pasar mas alla, y cosa que alguien vea un comentario que se sienta ofendido y que reporte el mensaje para que lo vean distintos moderadores de la red exchange y pueden ser baneados PERMANENTEMENTE

En tu caso, te saco una tarjeta Amarilla el moderador [@gbianchi](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/324/gbianchi) y ademas te da la explicacion cosa que veo fenomenal, cosa que en otra red exchange no sabrias el porque.

***En mi opinion*** y aqui vemos que tu mensaje no es lo que piensas, hizo bien en darte un ban, considero que fue una falta de respeto,y mas alla de la falta de respeto, creo que fue el momento indicado para que no dijeras cosas peores,

***mi conclusion*** te imaginas que alguien hubiece marcado tu mensaje como ***red flag*** y lo hubiese leido cualquier otro mod de la red? lo mas seguro y con todo el dolor te diria que tu cuenta quedaria suspendida, lo bueno, es que como fue un mod español, probablemente te dejen escribir en los siguientes dias en el chat y ya esto quedara a nada

Comment: La intensión de haber publicado esto en META fue que en algún momento pensé que mis palabras si podían haber sido una ofensa que toqué una fibra sensible que no era mi intensión hacerlo; y por ende haber podido pedir las disculpas correspondientes y haber explicado que nunca fue mi intensión ofenderlo. El motivo del ban ya fue explicado por la persona que fue la afectada y que también lo emitió, es decir por la única que podía responderme y se lo agradezco. Él en su respuesta no señala que se sintió ofendido o que fue una falta respeto, si no que fue un ***ban preventivo***

Comment: A mi ya me gustaría saber lo que la gente va a decir antes de que esa persona siquiera lo piense. Yo pensé que faltaba para llegar a los días de *Minority Report*

Comment: si quedo claro ya es mejor no darle la vuelta y seguir